# Infinite series summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{(4n+5)(4n+6)\cdots \cdots (4n+11)}$$

Try: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(4n+4)!}{(4n+11)!} = \frac{1}{6!}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(4n+4)!\cdot 6!}{(4n+4+6+1)!} = \frac{1}{6!}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\int^{1}_{0}x^{4n+4}(1-x)^6dx$$

$$ \frac{1}{6!}\int^{1}_{0}\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}x^{4n}\right)x^4(1-x)^6dx = \frac{1}{6!}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{x^4(1-x)^6}{1-x^4}dx$$

could some help me to solve it thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Another way:

$$\prod_{r=5}^{11}\dfrac{4n+11-(4n+5)}{4n+r}=\prod_{r=6}^{11}\dfrac1{4n+r}-\prod_{r=5}^{10}\dfrac1{4n+r}$$

See [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 1):

The telescoping series, as answered by lab bhattacharjee, is the good way to go.

With regard to the integral you properly wrote, using long division and partial fraction decomposition, $$\frac{x^4(1-x)^6}{1-x^4}=-x^6+6 x^5-15 x^4+20 x^3-16 x^2+12x-16+\frac{4 x}{x^2+1}+\frac{16}{x+1}$$